# Swapping every second character in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following problem: I would like to write a function in Python which, **given a string**, returns a **string** where **every group of two characters is swapped**.

For example given "ABCDEF" it returns "BADCFE".

The length of the string would be guaranteed to be an even number.

Can you help me how to do it in Python?

Comment: I smell homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its not homework, I am trying to solve a problem where two players are playing a game based on their previous moves and I keep the previous moves in a common history string and I need to swap characters to get from player A's view to player B's view.

Answer (score 5):

To add another option:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijkl'
>>> ''.join([c[1] + c[0] for c in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])])
'badcfehgjilk'
```

Comment: As per the OP: "the length of the string would be guaranteed to be an even number".

Comment: I would instead do it as `''.join(sum(zip(s[1::2], s[::2]), ()))`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I find this a bit confusing because of the `sum`. Probably a matter of personal preference, since it is quite concise.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `chain` avoids having to add all those tuples.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(.)(.)', r'\2\1', "ABCDEF")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest

''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(s[1::2], s[::2], fillvalue = '')))
```

You can also use `islice`s instead of regular slices if you have very large strings or just want to avoid the copying.

Works for odd length strings even though that's not a requirement of the question.

Answer (score 1):

While the above solutions do work, there is a very simple solution shall we say in "layman's" terms. Someone still learning python and string's can use the other answers but they don't really understand how they work or what each part of the code is doing without a full explanation by the poster as opposed to "this works". The following executes the swapping of every second character in a string and is easy for beginners to understand how it works.

It is simply iterating through the string (any length) by two's (starting from 0 and finding every second character) and then creating a new string (swapped_pair) by adding the current index + 1 (second character) and then the actual index (first character), e.g., index 1 is put at index 0 and then index 0 is put at index 1 and this repeats through iteration of string.

Also added code to ensure string is of even length as it only works for even length.

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123"

# use this prior to below iteration if string needs to be even but is possibly odd
if len(string) % 2 != 0:
    string = string[:-1]

# iteration to swap every second character in string
swapped_pair = ""
for i in range(0, len(string), 2):
    swapped_pair += (string[i + 1] + string[i])

# use this after above iteration for any even or odd length of strings
if len(swapped_pair) % 2 != 0:
    swapped_adj += swapped_pair[-1]

print(swapped_pair)

badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy21 # output if the "needs to be even" code used
badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy213 # output if the "even or odd" code used
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty solution:

```
def swapem (s):
    if len(s) < 2: return s
    return "%s%s%s"%(s[1], s[0], swapem (s[2:]))

for str in ("", "a", "ab", "abcdefgh", "abcdefghi"):
    print "[%s] -> [%s]"%(str, swapem (str))
```

though possibly not suitable for *large* strings :-)

Output is:

```
[] -> []
[a] -> [a]
[ab] -> [ba]
[abcdefgh] -> [badcfehg]
[abcdefghi] -> [badcfehgi]
```

Comment: This looks awfully much like my colleague's recent O(*n* lg *n*) binary search with list slicing.

Comment: Recursion is never the answer :)

Comment: @agf recursion is the answer iff recursion is the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer one-liners:

```
''.join(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,[[s[1+(x<<1)],s[x<<1]] for x in range(0,len(s)>>1)]))
```

Comment: OMG! What has Guido done to my beautiful language? :-) Just how am I supposed to teach _that_ to a third-grader?

Comment: This makes me sad! Use itertools to write crazy one-liners, not `lambda`s / `reduce` -- it's the Python way :)

Comment: That lambda-reduce combination is normally known as `sum`, that list comprehension can easily be replaced with some slicing and `zip`, and shifting instead of multiplying/dividing is a micro-optimization that doesn't even work.

Comment: To me shifting is more clear than 2*, but to each his own I guess. You're right about `sum`; I haven't used Python very much since 2.0 where it wasn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a another simple solution:

```
"".join([(s[i:i+2])[::-1]for i in range(0,len(s),2)])
```